# RegisterDeviceNotification fails with 1066 'service-specific error'

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

This error happens only in Debug configuration and in Windows vista/7. In Release or xp, everything works perfectly.

Any idea for why it might happen? And how might I find this service specific error?

Comment: Can we see how you call `RegisterDeviceNotification` perhaps? Our crystal balls are not working well today because of increased solar flare activity.

Comment: I call it fine. It appears that it only happens in virtual machines. Any clue?

Comment: No, no clue. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Probably you called RegisterDeviceNotification with a windows handle and DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE as flags. A windows handle requires DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE.